# CSS styles are not applied to HTML Element

Tags: css, reactjs

The parent container is normal but its children are not rendering. The text inside the div however is showing up. body-container styles are working but not body-menu and body-content. I have reloaded and restarted server multiple times.

```js
/* React Web Application */
import React from "react";
import './Projectbody.css';

export default function Projectbody() {
    return(
        <>
        <div className = "body-container">
        <div ClassName = "body-menu">menu</div>
        <div ClassName = "body-content">content</div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

```css
/* CSS Style File */
.body-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 94.5vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: orange;
}

.body-menu {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #43C0F6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.body-content {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #B2E4FA;
    display: flex;
}
```

The following image shows the application test image:

[image: Application Test Picture]

Comment: className not ClassName

Comment: goddamn it I knew it would be something so obvious. Gotta stop coding at 3am. Thanks man.

Comment: @DBS how do you mean? I probably dont need the <></> with a parent div now

Comment: you didnt close first div!

Comment: @HDM91 is that not what im doing below <div ClassName = "body-content">content</div> ??

Comment: yes i'm sorry , without indent its difficult to read code like that , your right

Comment: you can use eslint to prevent syntax errors like that

Comment: @HDM91 yeah i had tweaked my json settings so that emmet worked in react but idk its stopped working properly olus i turned my formatter off for some reason so its a little sloppy right about now :/